# How can I serialize a RealmObject to JSON in Realm for Java?

Tags: android, json, serialization, realm

I am implementing a DB for my Application and I am trying "connect" it to my REST interface. The data comes in as JSON and with the new JSON-Support (as of Realm 0.76) I can throw the JSON at my `Realm.createObjectFromJson(MyType.class, jsonString)` and it creates the appropiate obejcts and RealmLists.

But how can I do the opposite? That is, take a RealmObject and serialize it to JSON? It also should serialize any RealmList inside that object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Christian from Realm here.
Realm for Android currently doesn't have any such methods, although the core database actually supports JSON serialisation, so for now you would either have to do it manually or use a 3rd party tool like GSON (caveat, I havn't tested that scenario yet).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you give me a hint on how to manually do that? I (shallowly) tried to accomplish that by overriding the toString method. But it seams that I can only have setters/getters of my fields in my RealmObject-Classes and no other method besides.

Comment: I would probably have a Util class on the side that accepts your model class and outputs the JSON. You can construct the JSON in a number of ways. Manually or using JSONObject/JSONArray.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior What are the steps in manually doing it? Would you need to convert the RealmObject back to the original object?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior - When can we expect to see this feature?

Comment: We are not actively working on native JSON support at the moment, but we are about to merge this PR https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/1849. If you combine that with GSON you can convert back to JSON without using custom GSON serializers.

Answer (score 12):

Simply, all you need to do is:

```
Gson gson = //... obtain your Gson
YourRealmObject realmObj = realm.where(YourRealmObject.class).findFirst();
if(realmObj != null) {
    realmObj = realm.copyFromRealm(realmObj); //detach from Realm, copy values to fields
    String json = gson.toJson(realmObj);
}
```

Comment: Is this 'realmObj = realmObj.copyFromRealm();' or 'obj = realm.copyFromRealm(realmObj);'  ?? Second one worked for me.

Comment: @SakkeerHussain sorry I always think the RealmObject knows how to detach itself, but it's `realm.copyFromRealm(realmObject)`. I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: havent tested it yet. how about if the realm object has realm list inside, will it also be translated into a json array ?

Comment: @ralphspoon it **should**, considering the default `copyFromRealm()` calls the one that [takes a max depth parameter](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyFromRealm-E-int-) with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (and if you don't want the lists, use `maxDepth` param with `0`)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce this can be very inefficient. It's advisable to create your own gson TypeAdapter.

Comment: But it cause UI freezing for a heavy object for me

Comment: @GkMohammadEmon then don't do it on the UI thread?

Answer (score 7):

to deserialize JSON into RealmObject use on of the following

say you have a class definition like this

```
 @RealmClass
 public class Foo extends RealmObject{
  private String name;
  public void setName(String name){ this.name = name}
  public String getName(){ return this.name}
}
```

and a json payload like this:

```
 String json = "{\"name\":\"bar\"}";
 Foo fooObject= realm.createObjectFromJson(Foo.class, json);
 //or 
 String jsonArray = "[{\"name\":\"bar\"},{\"name\":\"baz\"}]";
 RealmList<Foo> fooObjects = realm.createAllFromJson(Foo.class, jsonArray);
```

However the reverse is not natively supported in realm-core. so this is how i work around it. i attempted to use **GSON**, but ended up writing too many codes that i myself did not understand so i implemented my own adapter like this.The problem is RealmObjects are not 'realm' `java.lang.Object`.

create an **adapter** that takes instance of your realm object and return its JSON representation.

**example.**

```
 public class RealmJsonAdapter{
    public JSONObject toJson(Foo foo){
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
     obj.putString("name",foo.getName());
     //if you have more fields you continue
     return obj;
     }
   }
```

you can now use this adapter in your classes to serialize you `RealmObject` to
**JSON**. prefferably you would make the adapter an interface so that you let callers (might be you yourself) pass you the adapter the want to use. 
you can then call say, `adapter.toJSON(realmObjectInstance)`. and get your JSONObject implementation
after all you care only about the JSON and not the RealmObject.

**NOTE**
This solution is a bit oudated. RealmObjects are now real java objects so you should be able to use it with GSON with no problems. Just make sure you are using version 0.89 or later and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Following is how you would do that with GSON library.

Suppose we have the following json reply from the server :

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "John",
         "surname": "Doe"
      }
   ]
}
```

For this Json object we create a helper class with corresponding properties

```
    public class JsonHelperClass {

    String id;
    String name;
    String surname;

    public JsonHelperClass() {
    }

    public JsonHelperClass(String id, String name, String surname) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}
```

Now in the following jsonReply is the string containing reply from server

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = new HttpManager().getJsonArrayFromReply(jsonReply);

    if(jsonArray == null || jsonArray.length <0){
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
        json = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        return null;
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        JsonHelperClass helperClass = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), JsonHelperClass.class);

        createRealmObject(helperClass);

}


    public void createRealmObject(JsonHelperClass helperClass){

        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);

        realm.beginTransaction();

        RealmDataObject obj = realm.createObject(RealmDataObject.class);

        obj.setId(helperClass.getId());
        obj.setName(helperClass.getName());
        obj.setSurname(helperClass.getSurname());

        realm.commitTransaction();


}

     public JSONArray getJsonArrayFromReply(String reply){

        JSONArray array = null;

        try {
            JSONObject jsonResp = new JSONObject(reply);
            array = jsonResp.getJSONArray("data");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return null;
        }

        return array;
    }
```

And the Realm Data Object

```
    public class RealmDataObject extends RealmObject {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public RealmDataObject() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }


}
```

Comment: This essentially does the serializing part of the process, wich is handled by Realm as of version 0.76. I wanted to do the opposite, that is, take a object and put it in its string represantation. For now, I just write my own deserializor and Im fine with it.

To your answer: As of version 0.77 of Realm you can omit your HelperClass because you dont need to create your obejcts *only* via Realm anymore. You can do a simple `new RealmDataObject()` and fill in the data or even simpler, let Gson do the work (as done in your example with the HelperClass)

Comment: I have to look into this...and is the RealmDataObject thread safe?

Comment: AFAIK yes, it is. Because all modifications to your RealmDataObject have to within a transaction, thus making them atomic and threadsafe.

Comment: Hi, im very interested to know more about RealmDataObject but cannot find anything, do you know any article ? thanks

Comment: Well, the        RealmDataObject is from your own example. I am just saying that you can omit your        JsonHelperClass and do the exakt same things you did with objects from that class now with objects directly from        RealmDataObject. So you could do what you alread do

    RealmDataObject obj = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), RealmDataObject.class);

and then, instead of copying everything from that object to another one, you simply call

    realm.copyToRealm(obj);

Comment: Ok..i got mixed up sry...the helper in this case is used since the add operation is done from a different thread..and realm objects in andoird are not thread safe

Comment: BUT, even simpler, there is no need to convert your JSONArray with Gson, you can simply call

    JSONArray jsonArray = new HttpManager().getJsonArrayFromReply(jsonReply);
    realm.createAllFromJson(RealmDataObject.class, jsonArray);
    
And now, even simpler, just throw your `jsonReply` at your `realm`

    realm.createAllFromJson(RealmDataObject.class, jsonReply); You dont need to convert anything. Just throw your string you get from the network at your realm...

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

```
  private JSONArray convertRealmintoJSONArray(Activity context){
    try {
        RealmResults<ModelMyCart> results = RealmControllerMyCart.with(context).getBooks();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for (ModelMyCart myCart : results
                ) {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_ID, myCart.getId());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_TITLE, myCart.getProduct_title());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_SIZE, myCart.getProduct_size());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_SELLINGFEE, myCart.getProduct_sellingfee());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_SELLINGFEE, myCart.getShipping_price());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_IMAGE, myCart.getProduct_image());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_BRAND, myCart.getProduct_brand());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID, myCart.getProduct_category_id());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NAME, myCart.getProduct_category_name());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_COLOR, myCart.getProduct_color());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_COLORTYPE, myCart.getProduct_colortype());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_CONDITION, myCart.getProduct_condition());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_CREATED_DATE, myCart.getProduct_created_date());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_MYSALEPRICE, myCart.getProduct_mysaleprice());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_ORIGINALPRICE, myCart.getProduct_originalprice());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_POTENTIALEARNINGS, myCart.getProduct_potentialearnings());
            object.put(Constants.PRODUCT_SHIPPINGCHARGES, myCart.getProduct_shippingcharges());
            object.put(Constants.USER_ID, myCart.getUser_id());
            object.put(Constants.USER_UNAME, myCart.getUser_uname());
            jsonArray.put(object);
        }
        Log.e("Converted",""+jsonArray);
        return jsonArray;
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case `new Gson().toJson(realm.copy(realmObj));` causes UI freezing *(sometimes out of memory exception)*. So I updated my Gson instance like that

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

String jsonString = gson.toJson(realm.copy(realmObj));
```