# How to convert RealmResult to Json using Gson library

Tags: json, gson, realm, realm-list

In this question [How can I serialize a RealmObject to JSON in Realm for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902904/how-can-i-serialize-a-realmobject-to-json-in-realm-for-java) The realm representative said that one can serialize realm object through GSON. Can you please explain it how?
I tried this.

```
 RealmResults<Dog> myDogs=realm.where(Dog.class).findAll();
 new Gson().toJson(myDogs);
```

But StackOverflowError occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make GSON serialization work with Realm you will need to write a custom JsonSerializer for each object that can be serialized and register it as a TypeAdapter.

You can see an example in this gist: https://gist.github.com/cmelchior/ddac8efd018123a1e53a

Comment: how can i pass the RealmResult and how will it return json String? Please explain. I couln't get from the above example. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question first time around. I have amended by answer.

Answer (score 1):

You get `StackOverflow` becouse of `Gson` based on reflection but managed object (`RealmObjectProxy`) have no real fields and fields of parent is `null`s also some of proxy fields produses recursion in field type recognition of `Gson` it happens in `$GsonTypes` class.

To serialize `RealmObject` you can use one of this options:

1. Write your own adapter for every `RealmObject` childs which will takes data using getters.
2. Call `realm.copyFromRealm(realmObject)` before serialisation. It will looks like `new Gson().toJson(realm.copyFromRealm(realmObject))`
3. Use library based on 2nd option [RealmSupportForGson](https://github.com/TrueNight/RealmSupportForGson)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is create a `List<Dog>` with `RLMResult<Dog>`, and then serialise this List with Gson.

Answer (score 0):

After two days of bug resolve, I found this simple solution:

```
YourRealmObject realmObj = realm.where(YourRealmObject.class).findFirst();
if(realmObj != null) {
    realmObj = realm.copyFromRealm(realmObj); //detach from Realm, copy values to fields
    String json = gson.toJson(realmObj);
}
```