# Error NotSerializableException in Realm

Tags: android, realm

I have this error when I try to send a realm object to another activity.

> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: io.realm.RealmList

I get data from the service, after that I store it to my model,  **I don't store it to Realm** (but it 's object extends realm ). Everything is ok but when I try to send this object `ProductInBag`to another activity this error happens.

My Model:

```
public class ProductInBag extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    int item_id;
    String type_id;
    int product_id;
    ....

    RealmList<ProductOptionInBag> options;
}
```

If I  try to use `realm.copyFromRealm(ProductInBag)`, it shows an error like its an un-managed object. 
Please help me if anyone knows about this problems. Thanks alot.

Comment: *I don't store it to Realm (but it 's object extends realm )* why?

Comment: Because I don't want to store a lot. I only store important data and this is not important (this data changes a lot). I did it with another object without `RealmList` inside and it 's ok.

Comment: store it anyway, and delete it when you have retrieved it in the 2nd activity

Comment: If you don't want to store it, why on earth is it a RealmObject? And why does it have RealmList field???

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I store it in another screen. But in this screen I don't want to store it.

Comment: Implement Parcelable

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments suggesting . I found reason of error: The object is un-managed object but cannot serialize RealmList inside this object.

And the simple way to solve this problem (it 's not official solution) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902904/how-can-i-serialize-a-realmobject-to-json-in-realm-for-java) : use GSON to convert object to **JSON String** and pass this **JSON String** to another activity, and convert it back to Object in the activity.