# How do you convert a .realm file to anything else

Tags: json, csv, realm

I have a realm database file that I would love to access the data from. I extracted it from an app on my phone. Unfortunately, I want to toy around with the data in ways beyond the capability of realm studio.

My question is, how do I convert the .realm file to another database form (JSON, CSV)? I am working on Windows 10.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902904/how-can-i-serialize-a-realmobject-to-json-in-realm-for-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after nearly 12 hours of grueling work, I finally was able to convert RealmObjects in my .realm file to a JSON file. And all in Java!

This process works for one model definition in your .realm file.

Here's how I did it:

1. Create a new app in android studio (because Realm for java is android-only) and start it with a simple activity preset.
2. Use gradle to import Realm-Java and GSON into your app
3. Using Realm Studio, export the desired Java model definitions of the classes in your realm file. (File -> Save model definitions -> Java)
4. Copy these .java files to the same folder as your MainActivity. I am going to refer to the name of these objects as `$YOUR_OBJECT$`
5. In your MainActivity, add

   ```
   Realm.init(this);
   RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
           .assetFile(getFilesDir().getPath() + "/NAME_OF_REALM_FILE.realm")

           .name("NAME_OF_REALM_FILE.realm")
           .schemaVersion(30)
           .build();

   Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
   final Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
   final Gson g = new Gson();
   ```

   to the `onCreate()` method.
6. Replace the contents of `onClick(View view)` with

   ```
           try {

               File output = new File(getFilesDir(), "output.json");
               BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output, true));
               RealmResults results = realm.where($YOUR_OBJECT$.class).findAll();
               Iterator<$YOUR_OBJECT$> iterator = results.iterator();
               writer.write("{\"Output\": {");
               while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                   $YOUR_OBJECT$ next = realm.copyFromRealm(iterator.next());
                   writer.write("\"" + <PUT SOMETHING HERE, LIKE AN ID> + "\": ");
                   writer.write(g.toJson(next));
                   writer.write(",");
               }
               writer.write("}}");

               writer.close();

           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
   ```
7. Pay EXTRA SPECIAL ATTENTION!! Your RealmObject must not have any circular references. Any sort of field that are Collections of other RealmObjects count. If your GSON object is overflowing, that is 100% why. To remove the circular reference, call `next.setREFERENCE(null);` before the `g.toJson()` call.
8. Place your .realm file in the files directory of the app (`data/data/com.app.name/files`)
9. Launch the app and press the button. Your output.json will generate in the same directory as the .realm file.

This process isn't perfect (there are some minor bugs you will encounter, but they are so minor I won't write about them), but I hope it helps you, like it would have helped me.