# How to convert a .realm file into .CSV or .json

Tags: realm

I extracted the code from an app and I would like to convert the .realm file into .CSV or .json. I'm using Windows 11 and I'm not really teach savvy. So far:

- I installed MongoDB Realm studio and tried to save the data into a json format but receive the error: "Failed to export the data invalid string length". I looked online but I didn't find any solution so far. I also tried to use the query to filter the list and reduce the data but it doesn't seems to work.
- I'm not able to use this workaround: https://www.npmjs.com/package/realm-exporter

What is the easiest way to convert a .realm file into a .csv or .json file ? Is there no easiest way than this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49962357/how-do-you-convert-a-realm-file-to-anything-else) ?

Comment: You cannot convert a Realm file into a .csv or really any other kind of file directly. It will take either and app or Realm Studio (as mentioned) to do that. I am able to open Realm files with Realm Studio and export as JSON, so it's working for me. My guess is you have incompatible versions of either Realm Studio or the .realm file. What version of Realm created the file, and what version of Realm Studio do you have?

Comment: You are right. I'm currently using version 11.1.1 of Realm studio. The file seems to have been created using a previous version.  However when opening it the first time with Realm studio a pop-up window appear: "The Realm file stores data in an outdated format   This file needs to be upgraded to a newer file format before it can be opened. Would you like a backup of the file before performing an irreversible upgrade of the file ?" To which I agree. Will try to downgrade the version of Realm studio I'm currently using.

Comment: That's exactly what's supposed to happen. HOWEVER - if you do that, the App that relies on that realm file will no longer work. It's important that the SDK in the app is updated at the same time the file is, otherwise things break. I would make a copy of the realm file and then use Realm Studio to update the copy. Leave the original alone, unless you're ready to update the SDK and re-build the app.

Comment: I did exactly as you suggested. It doesn't work. So I downgraded the version of realm. It now works but I have the following problem: "Failed to export data maximum call stack size exceeded".  Thank you very much :)

Comment: I don't know how to solve the above issue...

Comment: Are you saying Realm Studio is throwing that error? It's important to be clear when presenting data so we can reduce the back-and-forth comments. What version of Realm Studio are you trying to use? What version of the SDK? It *could* be a bug in Realm Studio, especially if there are a lot of recursive references. You may need to file a bug report. An alternative to Realm Studio is to craft and app that reads the data and JSON serializes it and then save it as a .csv file.